# tfidf.similarity is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest

I am trying to calc the text similarity by nodejs natural, that's the func in my expressjs server:

```
function calculateCosineSimilarity(query, scrapedData) {
  try {
    // Extract the content from scrapedData array and join it as a single string
    const scrapedText = scrapedData.map(data => data.content).join('\n');

    const tokens1 = tokenizer.tokenize(query);
    const tokens2 = tokenizer.tokenize(scrapedText);

    const tfidf = new natural.TfIdf();
    tfidf.addDocument(tokens1);
    tfidf.addDocument(tokens2);

    const cosineSimilarity = tfidf.similarity(0, 1); // Calculate the cosine similarity between document 0 (query) and document 1 (scrapedText)
    console.log('Cosine Similarity:', cosineSimilarity); // Log the cosine similarity
    return cosineSimilarity;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error calculating cosine similarity:', err);
    return 0; // Or any default value indicating the calculation failed
  }
}
```

and I am getting this error:

> Error calculating cosine similarity: TypeError: tfidf.similarity is not a function